# com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart library show value at wrong position

Tags: java, android, graph

I am using `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart` library for android graph but it show 
dataset value at wrong position as shown below:

[line graph with two sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPzo4.png)

In above picture purple color `lineSet` shows value at wrong `yAxis` value.

My code to set values is:

```
if (chart_lab.getData() != null && chart_lab.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
    set1 = (LineDataSet) chart_lab.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
    set1.setValues(values);
    set2 = (LineDataSet) chart_lab.getData().getDataSetByIndex(1);
    set2.setValues(hbpVals2);

    /*ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets
    dataSets.add(set2);

    // create a data object with the datasets
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);

    chart_lab.setData(data);*/
    chart_lab.getData().notifyDataChanged();
    chart_lab.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart_lab.animateY(500);
} else {
    // create a dataset and give it a type
    set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Diastolic BP(mmHg)");
    set1.setCubicIntensity(0.1f);
    set1.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
    set1.enableDashedHighlightLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
    set1.setColor(Color.RED);
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
    set1.setLineWidth(2f);
    set1.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    set1.setCircleRadius(4f);
    set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
    set1.setValueTextSize(9f);
    //set1.setDrawFilled(true);
    set1.setFormLineWidth(1f);
    set1.setFormLineDashEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10f, 5f}, 0f));
    set1.setFormSize(15.f);

    set2 = new LineDataSet(hbpVals2, "Systolic BP(mmHg)");

    set2.setCubicIntensity(0.1f);
    set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
    set2.setColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    set2.setCircleColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    set2.setLineWidth(2f);
    set2.setCircleRadius(4f);
    set2.setFillAlpha(65);
    set2.setFillColor(Color.RED);
    set2.setDrawCircleHole(false);
    set2.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets
    dataSets.add(set2);

    // create a data object with the datasets
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);

    // set data
    chart_lab.setData(data);
    chart_lab.animateY(500);
    chart_lab.invalidate();
    chart_lab.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

Please help if anyone knows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solved my problem just by removing below line from above code:

```
set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
```